# Javascript/HTML5 trying to create a BinaryStreamReader

Tags: javascript, oop, html, methods

I'm trying to create a simple binaryStreamReader in javascript. Currently I have the following:

```
function BinaryStreamReader(file){
    var reader = new FileReader();


    this.readBytes = function(start, bytes){

        reader.readAsBinaryString(file.slice(start,bytes));

        reader.onload = function(e){
            return e.target.result; //<-- this doesn't work now :P
        }

        reader.onerror = function(e){
            alert("FileError: " + e.target.error.code);
        }
    }
}
```

However, I want to use it like this

```
var bsr = new BinaryStreamReader();
var data = bsr.readBytes(0,128);
```

Obviously, readBytes() isn't returning anything in my class. Is it possible to let it return whatever onLoad returns?

Comment: Please rename your question to "Java BinaryStreamReader" and retag it as "java" :-)

Comment: It's javascript :p in combination with the HTML5 File Api.

Comment: Is the result correct? or is it the return where you found trouble with?
pls console log the result.

Comment: Well, what the problem is. Is that I call the bsr.ReadBytes() method. Yet, it doesn't return anything. It only calls a method that triggers an event. I'm trying to find out if it's possible to let the event return something to the readBytes() method.

Comment: I swear I saw the word "Java" somewhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    
function BinaryStreamReader(file){
    var reader = new FileReader();

    this.callback = null;

    this.ready = function(callback) {
        if(callback) {
            this.callback = callback;
        }
    }

    this.readBytes = function(start, bytes){

        reader.readAsBinaryString(file.slice(start,bytes));

        reader.onload = function(e){

            if(this.callback !== null) {
                this.callback(e.target.result);
            }
        }

        reader.onerror = function(e){
            alert("FileError: " + e.target.error.code);
        }
        return this;
    }
}

var bsr = new BinaryStreamReader();
var data = bsr.readBytes(0,128).ready(function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

this should do the trick...